# Ошибка при выборе данных из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Делаю интернет-магазин(первый), столкнулся с ошибкой, которую самому пока устранить не удалось. Приведу куски кода, которые есть у меня.

1) Файл **config.php** содержит следующий код:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$passwordname = '';
$basename = 'web-shop';
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwordname, $basename) 
or die ('Невозможно открыть базу');
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

function db_result_to_array($result)
 {
    $res_array = array();
    $count = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
       $res_array[$count] = $row;
       $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
 }

 function List_categories($WhereCat)
 {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY Name_cat";
    if ($WhereCat!="") 
    {
      $sql.= "Where (pop=".$WhereCat.")";
    };
    $result = db_result_to_array($conn->query($sql));
    return $result;

 }
```

2) В файле **index.php** (к которому подключен config.php) пишу следующий код по формированию меню:

```
  <a href="">Товары</a>
  <ul>
  <?php
    $result = List_categories("");
    while ($row = $result)
    {
     echo '<li><a href="index.php?cat='.$row['id_cat'].'">'.$row['Name_cat'].'</a></li>';
    }                     
  ?>
```

При просмотре страницы в браузере выдается следующая ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\config.php on line 34
```

Тоесть ошибка срабатывает на данной строке в config.php:

```
$result = db_result_to_array($conn->query($sql));
```

В чем моя ошибка? Подскажите...

Comment:  Если List_categories("") это метод класса, почему нет объекта?


Comment: это не метод класса, а просто независимая функция.

Comment: Написал еще одну независимую функцию в файле config.php:

    function Name_current_category($id)
     {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories Where id_cat=".$id;
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     return $row['Name_cat'];
     }

А в файле index.php пишу следующее:

    $Category = Name_current_category(1);

И выдает такую же ошибку.

    Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\config.php

Что за ерунда происходит с кодом? Помогите товарищи!

Comment: $conn то откуда функция знает ? я чё-то не вижу там global. (я не про то что global обязателен, а про то что $conn не определен в функции - можно передать параметром, объявить global или прочее)

Comment: пробовал и через глобал делать, такая же ерунда. Вообще-то $conn и функция Name_current_category находятся в одном файле, так что они по идее должны видеть друг друга и без глобальности переменной.

Comment: [вы не правы](http://ideone.com/YffQw4)

Comment: ну хорошо, сделал я как вы сказали, но такая же ошибка на строке $result = $conn->query($sql);

Comment: а как я сказал сделать ? я просто сказал в чём ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

```
function List_categories($WhereCat) {
global $conn;
...
}
```

должно помочь. вообще такой стиль написания кода очень плох. в том числе и из-за необходимости использовать глобальные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы определились используете `Mysqli_*` или `mysql_*`, а то все перемешали. Подключаетесь `mysqli`, а фетчите `mysql_*`.

Comment: ну я использую вообще-то mysqli. Описался тут немного... но ошибка возникает на строке **$result = $conn->query($sql);**

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Вы же Mysqli используете? Вообще не код а мясо. ИМХО.

Comment: уже поправил свою опечатку. Но суть проблемы не в этом, как я уже сказал. Код ругается на этапе $conn->query($sql).

Comment: вы неправильно взаимодействуете с mysqli
<?php
    function res_to_arr($res) {
        $result = array();
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
            $result[] = $row;
        return $result;
    }

    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $res->free();
    echo "s";